# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, random-forest

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

When i run it in jupyter notebook after adding

```
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'
```

I am getting an error like this.
[library i added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaMa6.png)
and
[the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKgYQ.png)

I was trying to apply random forest, which is a machine learning model. However, it didn't work and I got such an error and couldn't solve it. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't make us look at images.  Post all code and error messages as plain text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.float` was removed as of 1.24. It looks like the package you're using relies on an older version of Numpy. You could either: update sklearn to a newer version that doesn't use `np.float` (if it exists) or downgrade your Numpy version to 1.23.5.

Comment: It still doesn't work when I downgrade to Numpy 1.23.5

Comment: Maybe you could downgrade to an even earlier version. Also, if you have multiple versions of Python installed, it’s possible you’re downgrading Numpy on one version of Python but your project is running on another. Double check your version of Python and Numpy at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I found out that it's not using Numpy 1.23.5. I chose to change the code instead :D